# Can a Sikh enter a buddhist temple with a turban?

Tags: theravada, karma, traditions, vinaya

As I went to worship at one of the most famous & sacred temples in Sri Lanka a Sikh person entered with his turban. As per the religious traditions we are not allowed to wear any head coverings while entering the temple & worshiping. 
When the particular person was asked to remove it he didn't & he worshiped with the turban saying it complies with the international laws. I see this disrespectful as,

1. It's a must for visitors entering the Sikh temples to wear a head cover.
2. Even the Kings have removed their crown when worshiping Lord Buddha.
3. As per the scripts many religious leaders who were there during the time of Lord Buddha has paid a lot of respect & has considered Lord Buddha superior.

Can I please have your views regarding this.

May the Noble Triple Gems bless you!

Answer (score 4):

As a sign of respect and being inline with accepted customs it is best that the person removes the turban.

I guess they might have been allowed in the accommodation of Sikh religious custom of wearing the turban.

Being accommodating does no harm also, as long as a person is not wearing the turban as contempt or disrespect.

Comment: I'm confused. Why must a Sikh remove a turban when western tourists can enter wearing their gold crosses and this is not considered disrespectful? I've never seen an officiant adress a westerner about his anywhere in S-E Asia.

Comment: Generally, one must remove headgear, footwear and also wear a long dress when one visits a temple. There is no need to remove a cross or any other religious symbol. In the case of the turban worn by a Sikh, is headgear which might be removed if the person is OK with it.

Comment: Don't you think that there should be some regulations imposed by the temples re. this matter. As I went through the sites I found that no tourist is allowed to enter a Sikh shrine without covering the head. I think we too need to protect our traditions & customs in a more strict manner.

Comment: I guess there are checkers who check for disrespectful clothing. It is up to them. And also "house rules" imposed by each temple.